# Move answer to related question

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I have search questions but I did not found any related with this.

Is it possible to move valid answer to another question which is asking for same help.

I found that there are lots extra ordinary answers for low quality questions (below -5 votes, which are either close or on-hold).

I don't know the actual procedure but if there is a possibilities that question may be close in future than we can lose valuable answers.

Just curious that how these things manage, does moderator can move this answer to related question?

Comment: If questions a duplicates, vote to close them a duplicates.

Comment: I'm asking about answers.

Comment: Vote to close as duplicate, and if they are exact duplicates, you might want to flag for merging, if there is at least one answer contributing something over the dupe-targets answers.